# Skipping lines when parsing a yaml file

Tags: python, file, parsing, yaml, argparse

I'm trying to create a script where you can import a yaml file and validate if it is in yaml format. I also want it to list every error in the file. What I'm trying to do is leverage the yaml safe load, then when it fails print the error message, ignore that line, then reread the file, and repeat until all errors in the file are printed. Is there an easy way to ignore a list of lines when importing a file? Heres my current code:

```
#Verify YAML modules is installed
try:
    import yaml
except:
    print ('You do not have the YAML module installed.\n'+'Run: pip install yaml to fix this' )
    quit()
#Verify argparse module is installed
try:
    import argparse
except:
    print ('You do not have the argparse module installed.\n'+'Run: pip install argparse to fix this' )
    quit()
import itertools
#Loop variable
i = 0

#Configuration for argument parsing
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("path", help='File/Directory path to be examined', type=str)
args = (parser.parse_args())

#The main loop
while (i == 0):
    skip = []
   #Loop to skip lines for re-iteration
    with open(args.path) as infile:
        for line in itertools.islice(infile, skip, None):
            #Verify file is in YAML, if so save as dict then end
            try:
                yml = yaml.load(txt, yaml.SafeLoader)
                print yml
                i == 1 
            #if not yaml record error seen, then redo the loop skipping previous errors
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print ("Error while parsing YAML file:")
                if hasattr(exc, 'problem_mark'):
                          mark = exc.problem_mark
                          print "Error position: (%s:%s)" % (mark.line+1, mark.column+1)
                          print exc
                          skip.add(mark.line+1)
```

Comment: I don't think the high level logic is sound; the yaml can become unparseable by removing a line from it, so you could end up with an issue where skipping the line and reparsing the file will never validate.

Comment: hmmm, well is there another way to list all yaml errors in a file besides that. I guess I can see what your saying. but lets say line 2 and line 78 had issues, with the safe load method I am using it will show me the error on line 2 then stop. The user using the script would basically have to run the script, fix 1 line, run the script, fix another line, which takes longer than fixing all the errors at once(If I can figure out how to display them at once)

Comment: @VincentMorris You could try to skip all the lines until you find the same indent level as before the error and restart from there. There are a few caveats with that though: 1) your error indicator might indicate line 1, although the actual correction is several lines forward 2) The SafeLoader cannot load YAML with tags 3) You are using PyYAML which has unfixed bugs, including ones that throw errors on perfectly fine YAML 4) PyYAML still has no support for the  YAML 1.2  specification (from 2009).

Comment: Hmm did not know there was an issue with pyaml, is there an alternative module you would recommend? I used the ruamel yaml module in the past.

Comment: @Anthon So I found a tool called yamllint. it seems to do what I want. Just gotta figure out how to leverage the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOOOT! I FIXED IT!!!

Theres a great tool called Yamllint that I leverage to do exactly what I want:

```
#Verify YAML modules is installed
try:
    import yaml
except:
    print ('You do not have the YAML module installed.\n'+'Run: pip install pyaml to fix this' )
    quit()
#Verify argparse module is installed
try:
    import argparse
except:
    print ('You do not have the argparse module installed.\n'+'Run: pip install argparse to fix this' )
    quit()

try:
    import yamllint
except:
    print ('You do not have the yamllint module installed.\n'+'Run: pip install yamlint to fix this' )
    quit()
from subprocess import call
#call(["ls", "-l"])

#Configuration for argument parsing
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("path", help='File/Directory path to be examined', type=str)
args = (parser.parse_args())

#The main loop

#Verify file is in YAML, if so save as dict then end
ignore = set([])
with open(args.path, "r") as f:
    try:
        yml = (yaml.load(f))
        print yml
    #If not yaml run through yamllint
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        call(["yamllint","-f","parsable",args.path])
```

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you have to write the complete parser yourself. Error recovery is something which can only properly be implemented by the parser, not in a later stage. I give you some examples of why your approach or any other post-parser approach won't work:

```
foo: | lorem
  ipsom dolor: - it amet
```

Here, we start a literal block scalar but begin the content on the same line as the indicator `|`. This is forbidden. If you ignore the first line, your YAML looks like:

```
  ipsom dolor: - it amet
```

Which is a YAML error because you cannot start a compact sequence after a colon. But wait – this content was originally inside a block scalar, so it wouldn't have resulted in an error!

Now let's go with Anthon's proposal to skip all lines until the previous indentation:

```
foo: !!map
  !!map {
    lorem: &a ipsum
  }
bar: *a
```

Here, the second `!!map` is illegal because a node may only have one tag. So you remove all lines from the second `!!map` on until you find a line with the same indentation as the previous (`foo: ...`) line:

```
foo: !!map
bar: *a
```

You get an error telling you that `*a` does not reference an anchor, because you removed the line containing the anchor. But it also can happen without anchors:

```
foo: {
    !!str !!str lorem: ipsum
  }
bar: baz
```

Again, you remove the lines until `bar: baz`:

```
foo: {
bar: baz
```

Now you have an unmatched `{`. I could go on and on. The actual problem lies within language theory: If some string contains one YAML error, it is not a valid YAML string. You cannot find „other YAML errors“ in it because there is no defined point where to continue (in the source: *at which character should I continue parsing after an error?* in the parser: *at which state should I continue parsing after an error?*).

In order to catch subsequent errors, you need to define those recovery points *in the parser*; you are currently only trying to define the recovery points *in the source* by skipping content, which is not enough.